# Ebay API: Cannot get proper user token generated for production

Tags: ebay-api

I've been banging my head against the wall on this for most of the day, and I just cant seem to get a correct user auth token. I am able to make calls to GetOfficalTime and GetItem, but when I try to do ReviseItem, I get "This item cannot be accessed because the listing has been deleted, is a Half.com listing, or you are not the seller." This item is active, not a Half.coom listing, and I am the seller (though the token says no). I've quadruple checked my key info as well.

I've tried to User Token Tool, I've tried Get a Token from eBay via Your Application, I've tried this -> https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=1661, but they all return the same error.

When I do Get User Token Here, then pass it directly to the API Tool to see if it works, it comes back as invalid as well. The only token Ive gotten to work is by doing that through oAuth, which works in the API Tool, but does not work when I add it to the Authorization header when making the Reviseitem call.

I own the eBay account that I'm trying to do the Reviseitem on and have typed my password in over 100 times trying to figure this out.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've scraped these forums high and low (Google too) and nothing I find seems to allow me to get a token and revise my items.